# Can a laptop CPU temperature of 90 degrees Celsius cause damage?

Tags: laptop, cpu

I have seen that my CPU temperature comes around 90C when some processing is done.
The lower part becomes so hot that I can't touch it.

1. Can it do some damage to laptop?
2. Can I cause some fire if I put laptop on bed for long hours?
3. I always keep laptop power cord on , will that cause damage to laptop battery?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. AMD/Intel have their CPU's graded for up to 100C so it shouldn't cause any damage. As for the heat on the bottom perhaps a CPU cooling pad is a worthy investment.
2. If you put it on the bed for long hours you run more of a risk of the laptop reaching its critical temp and it shutting itself down. Which is not the best for the laptop but it shouldn't start much on fire.
3. Laptop batteries are commonly Lithium Ion Batteries. They like a bit of power level fluctuation. Let it drain some every day before you plug it in. I like to let my battery reach Yellow before I plug it in.